# Communication between a PHP service an Android device

Tags: php, android

I wonder if there is any way in PHP, to know if an Android device is connected to the network, or wifi, ping to device or something like that.
Any idea? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question seems to be too broad right now but I'd use one of these two approaches:

1) If you need to test it from a remote server using PHP, use a `Socket` from the PHP side.  Simply make your `Android` device accept connections as it was a server and once you establish the socket, you'll know if it's up/down.

2) Even easier from this approach would be establishing a `Socket` directly from the android device and if you can establish it, send your status to the remote server. One way would be setting a `Socket` against google, like this:

You may simply declare a `Socket`. I use the following code on many of my projects and the timeout definitely works.

```
Socket socket;
final String host = "www.google.com";
final int port = 80;
final int timeout = 30000;   // 30 seconds

try {
  socket = new Socket();
  socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), timeout);
}
catch (UnknownHostException uhe) {
  Log.e("GoogleSock", "I couldn't resolve the host you've provided, I'm probably having a connection issue!");
}
catch (SocketTimeoutException ste) {
  Log.e("GoogleSock", "After a reasonable amount of time, I'm not able to connect, my connection is probably down!");
}
catch (IOException ioe) {
  Log.e("GoogleSock", "Hmmm... Sudden disconnection, probably you should start again!");
}
```

Comment: Php socket I had thought, but as it should inquire as to the ip of a android device changes, if you connect via wifi or 3G

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library for Android called Parse: https://parse.com/docs/android_guide

Read through their docs. In short you will have to have a service listening for when a device comes online (your app can send that ping).

You have to be more clear in your question if you want a more clear answer. Hope this works for you.